# How can I change the colour of an unordered list that has an unknown depth and is generated recursively?

Tags: python, html, css, sass

I have a dictionary:

```
tree['node-A'] = {
    'class-type': 'Date' 
    'class-type-index': 0
}

tree['node-B'] = {
    'class-type': 'Ratio' 
    'class-type-index': 1
}

tree['node-C'] = {
    'class-type': 'Integer' 
    'class-type-index': 2
}
```

And in the HTML I generate the classes like so:

```
<ul>
{%for key, value in tree.items %} 
    {%include "tree_view_template.html" %}
{%endfor%}
</ul>

<li class="{{ node.class-type}} index-{{node.class-type-index}}">
 {{node.key}}
    {%if node.has_childs %}
        <ul>
         {%for ch in node.all_childs %}
              {%with node=ch template_name="tree_view_template.html" %}
                   {%include template_name%}
              {%endwith%}
         {%endfor%}
         </ul>
    {%endif%}
</li>
```

Ignore any grammar mistakes or syntax errors. The important part is:

```
So in the end I will have something like:

<li class="Date index-0">
<li class="Ratio index-1">
<li class="Integer index-2">
<li class="Boolean index-3">
..
```

So the quesiton is, how can I, in Sass, start from index-0 going all the way to index-N and darken the colour each time I drill down the list?

Right now I am doing this just to get an idea, but obviously this is completely the wrong way to do things.

```
$base-colour: some very light shade of green;

.index-0 {
    background-color: $base-colour;
}

.index-1 {
    darken( $base-color, 5%)
}

.index-2{
    darken( $base-color, 10%)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I supposed that exists a depth limit, so you can use a simple 'for' to generate the css like this:

```
$class: "index";
$base-color: green;
$depth-limit: 5;

@for $i from 0 through $depth-limit {
  .#{$class}-#{$i} { 
    background-color: darken($base-color, 5 * $i);
  }
}
```